# My raspberry pi is having issues booting (It kinda boots) (Need help please)

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

I have a pi (Obviously), but it won't boot fully. I have the SD card that came with it (I payed extra for the pre-formatted one) and it boots just fine, shows the normal console, and I don't see any errors (one command failed to execute according to it, but it said it ignored it and it didn't look important). Once it's done booting, it shows a black screen. No mouse cursor, no way to input anything. I was wondering what I could do? I am running raspbian 11 or 13 (don't remember which). My friend brought over RISC OS and it didn't boot either, it hung at the console. Any help is appreciated!!! (I need it for a project if you may be able to help but it's not the end of the world.)

Comment: It might be useful if you let us know which model specifically (e.g. B+) and what output you are using to connect (e.g. HDMI). Personally the first thing I'd be looking at is What the LEDs are doing. (They function different on the B+).

Comment: What were you wondering - "what I could do?" 
what do you expect from your Pi?

Comment: The black screen may be the normal console.  Not all distributions launch a graphical user interface.  What happens if you type on the keyboard?  Is anything echoed to the screen?

Comment: I have the model B, and I set it up to boot into xwindows after boot. I need to try a different power supply, but the ACT button doesn't blink in a pattern, it's abnormal. Also, I'm using RCA (analog) for my video output. Read my comment on the answer and you'll see what I found out.

Answer (score 2):

I would check the power supply (or borrow from your friend). Many power supplies do not provide enough juice even when they say they would.

If you have the model with Ethernet, you may want to check if it assigned the IP and try to ssh from there. If you could login, that means your monitor is not accepting the signal after the boot (you can configure various HDMI settings using config.txt file).

Comment: I have the model B, and I set it up to boot into xwindows after boot. I need to try a different power supply, but the ACT button doesn't blink in a pattern, it's abnormal.

Comment: Also, I just tried a keyboard, and it does the funky text thing where you press a button and it prints out a random key (not the one you pressed). So yes, it does mirror text, just not in the normal way. It doesn't go to a command line, it just prints random keys. I'm assuming this is a software-level issue that can be fixed?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a software issue assuming your keyboard works elsewhere. Try a better power supply.

Comment: My keyboard driver is corrupted, I need to reinstall raspbian anyway. I think that's my issue seeing that part of the screen is clipped off, I didn't set it to auto-boot into xwindows, and It's probably clipping off the command-line "example/example> " part. Thanks for the help though!